# calculate maximum value possible from a given number of bits

Tags: python, bit

I have a function which will need to be passed an arbitrary number of bits, for example 7. Is there a straitforward way to calculate the largest number available with that number of bits. Eg, if I passed in 8, the function would return 255.

Is there a straightforward/effieicnt way to do this?

Comment: `(2**n)-1` to quickly give the largest value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just do (I'd say this is pretty straightforward and efficient):

```
def max_bits(b):
    return (2 ** b) - 1
```

Demo:

```
>>> max_bits(8)
255
```

---

This works since binary place values are always exponents of 2, so this is probably the simplest and easiest to understand.

Comment: Need to subtract 1 for the largest value

Answer (score 8):

Left-shift the number 1 by the number of bits, subtract one:

```
def max_bits(b):
    return (1 << b) - 1
```

Demo:

```
>>> max_bits(8)
255
>>> max_bits(256)
115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935L
```

Bitshifting is faster than using the exponent of 2:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> def max_bits_bitshift(b):
...     return (1 << b) - 1
... 
>>> def max_bits_exp(b):
...     return (2 ** b) - 1
... 
>>> timeit.timeit('f(256)', 'from __main__ import max_bits_exp as f')
2.767354965209961
>>> timeit.timeit('f(256)', 'from __main__ import max_bits_bitshift as f')
0.49823594093322754
```

That's more than 5 times faster for a 256-bit number!

Comment: premature optimization.

Comment: @ErikAllik: Why is this premature optimization? I just happen to know this in the more efficient method; it is not as if the other option is more readable or easier to maintain.

Comment: @ErikAllik: How else are people going to discover what method to use when they *do* need to optimize their code? A 5 times speed difference can make a huge difference when you are creating a bitmask in a crucial loop somewhere. This is a Stack Overflow answer, chances are it'll stay up and be used as a reference by *many* people of the next few years, and information like this is important to someone who *is* optimizing.

Comment: The first option is definitely more readable for many if not most readers of the code; in any case, I just added the comment for those who might think they *have* to use a faster approach.